# PNG not rendering in next js using next/image

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I am working  on a Next JS project.

```
<Image src="/assets/icons/hand.png" alt="hand" width={30} height={30} />
<img src="/assets/icons/hand.png" alt="hand2" width={30} height={30} />
```

The first image using next/image is not working for png files. The second image works.

Also this problem does not exist for .svg files. They correctly render when using next/image.

The error is:

```
The requested resource isn't a valid image for /assets/icons/hand.png received text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Any hints please?

Comment: Do you have "hand.png" in public/assets/icons folder?

Comment: yes i do.. 
thats why the normal img tag image displays..

i am guessing there is some setting for next/image which right now accepts only svgs and not pngs. unable to figure out what that could be.

Comment: Can you please add few more details like, are using App Router or Pages Router ? Folder Structure of your project ? NextJS Version ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image
  src="/assets/icons/hand.png"
  alt="hand"
  width={30}
  height={30}
  onError={(e) => {
    console.error("Error loading image:", e);
  }}
  unoptimized={true} // Disable image optimization temporarily
/>
```